# $_POST array returning empty on live site - fine on localhost.

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a codeigniter application on an Amazon EC2 server. The server is set up using Apache2 and php5. I have tested the application on localhost and it works fine however on he EC2 server it does not. The problem is this. Whenever I pass form data to the controller and print the $_POST variable it returns empty. This only occurs on the live site but not in localhost. I have absolutely no idea why would cause this. I have checked the config settings for the below and see nothing out of the ordinary:

[image]

This of course would lead me to believe there might be something wrong on the server side but it could equally be a codeigniter setting I may be overlooking.

Comment: There's no CI setting that i know that would affect this, If you can visit the page regularly with an http-GET request, you should be able to do the same with a POST request.

Can you visit the url at all?

Comment: Yes, the site works perfectly. Socialplus.niall.ws I have it set to print anything in the sign up or sign in forms.

Comment: http://socialplus.niall.ws/login/signin -- when i visit this link(where the post POSTS to), i get a 404 in the network debugger of the browser, what's not loading properly?

Comment: When you submit, it is sent to the function (in the controller) and the $_POST should be printed on the screen. However this isn't the case.

Comment: Yes but why is the browser returning 404? it seems like it can't reach the POST url for some reason

Comment: I'm not getting that. I get an empty array on page...

Comment: Ah yes, I see that in the console log. Sorry. Was wondering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61587/discussion-between-patrick-and-niall-lonergan).

Comment: have you found any solution?